# Can we pass dataframe as a parameter to a function in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
def is_Data_Valid():
    emp_df.withColumn(
        "ValidationErrors",
        f.when(
            f.col("Name").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$") & f.col("Age").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Experience").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col("Year").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Dept").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
            f.lit("0")
        ).otherwise(f.lit("Invalid data"))
    )
```

I have this above function for validation, but here in this I can only validate the data of one dataframe "emp*df" but there is another dataframe "emp1*f_df".

So to avoid repeatation can I pass data frame to function and call function twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass dataframe to the function, see the code below.

```
def is_Data_Valid(df):
    df = df.withColumn(
        "ValidationErrors",
        f.when(
            f.col("Name").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$") & f.col("Age").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Experience").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col("Year").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Dept").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
            f.lit("0")
        ).otherwise(f.lit("Invalid data"))
    )

    return df
```

You can call the function with passing the dataframes you want like this,

```
df_1_checked = is_Data_Valid(emp_df)
df_2_checked = is_Data_Valid(emp_1_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in the `DataFrame` as parameter, like so:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def is_Data_Valid(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    return df.withColumn(
        "ValidationErrors",
        f.when(
            f.col("Name").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$") & f.col("Age").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Experience").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col("Year").cast("int").isNotNull() & f.col(
                "Dept").rlike("^[a-zA-Z]+$"),
            f.lit("0")
        ).otherwise(f.lit("Invalid data"))
    )
```

Remember to always **return** the DataFrame from such function - the PySpark functions are not executed *in-place*, rather each DataFrame is immutable so you have to create a new instance, whenever any transformation is executed.